# Inheriting a computer - repository not found

Tags: git, github

I inherited a computer and copied my files to it. I did `git config --global user.name "my name"` and `git config --global user.email "my email"`. For one repository it worked, but for the other one it didn't.

I got the error that the repository doesn't exist.

In this case I couldn't reset the computer to the factory settings as I'm going to need many things from it, I just have to switch the git user to me.

How do I do this?

Comment: The `git config` commands you ran, AFAIK, don't really have anything to do with specific repositories.  Maybe you should tell us everything you have done so far.

Comment: when you use `--global` option it means that it is not dependent to any repository and is a **Global** config.

Comment: Maybe the repository really does not exist anymore?

Comment: Did you locate any .git repertories around ? These are repos.